# Difference between subscribeNext and bindNext

Tags: ios, rx-swift, reactivex

I am using RxSwift and wondering what is difference between subscribeNext and bindNext?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

bindNext(*:) includes error handling. It calls subscribe(*:onError:) and throws a fatal error onError (in DEBUG). subscribeNext(_:) only handles onNext and does not throw an error.

Thanks for Scott Gardner from http://as.ync.io/